# Decimal precision vs. number of digits in printf(), fprintf() in format %g vs. %f

Tags: c, printf, string-formatting

After surfing for a while I could not find a clear explanation for this issue. Maybe anyone could clarify me why it works so.

In some code I am saving some `double` numbers to file by `fprintf` (after properly initializing the file stream). Because, a priori, I don't know what number is passed to my program, and in particular, what its format is, e.g. `0.00011` vs. `1.1e-4`, I thought to use the format specifier `%.5g` instead of `%.5f`, where, I want to save my data with a 5-digit decimal precision.

However, it turns out that in `%g` the decimal precision of my saved numbers is correct if the numbers have a integer part equal to `0`, otherwise is not, like for example:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("mydata.dat","w+"); //Neglecting error check for brevity
double value[2] = {0.00011,1.00011};
printf("\ng-format\n");
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ 
    frintf(fp,"%.5g\n",value[i]);
    printf("%.5g\n",value[i]);
}
printf("\n\nf-format\n");
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    frintf(fp,"%.5f\n",value[i]);
    printf"%.5f\n",value[i]);
} 
fclose(fp);
```

This produces the following output to file (and on the std stream):

```
g-format
0.00011
1.0001

f-format
0.00011
1.00011
```

So, why the choice of `%g` is 'eating' decimal digits as soon as the integer part is not zero?

Comment: **%6g** means 6 significant figures, a leading 0 is not considered a sig. Fig.  **%6f** always means 6 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification: the keyword in the manual was "significant digits"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The %g print x digits from the first digit which is not 0.
So if the x + 1 digit is not in the integer part, it will round it. And if the x + 1 digit is in the integer part it will display your number as scientific notation (rounded too)

The %f just display integer part plus x digit after.

Answer (score 1):

It's not eating decimal digits. With %g the field width specifies the number of significant digits; 1.0001 has 5 significant digits, which is what "%.5g" calls for. That's different from %f, where the field width specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Both yours and Spouark's reply are clear. I'll approve Spouark's one though to help him gaining points.

Answer (score 0):

To answer what appears to be OP's higher problem:

> I want to save my data with a 5-digit decimal precision.

If code needs to save values with 6 total significant figures, use `.5e` which will print all values* with a non-zero leading digit and 5 places after a decimal point in exponential notation.  Do not bother with `"%g"`.

*Of course a value of `0.0` does not print with a leading non-zero digit.